# Is there anyway to create captcha using angular, by converting random captcha text to image and display in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, captcha

Saw this video [Converting random text to image using PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL9AitvjZKg)

What i am trying to implement is , i would like to create a random text and use this as captcha. And while displaying it in HTML page , the captcha should be displayed as an image so that it adds more security.

By watching the above mentioned video , i found that it is possible in PHP, but i need this to implemented in angular.

Can anyone help me out here ? A sample code will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, creating a captcha on a client-side isn't secure. Your code will available for any user. Using server-side is a better decision. But If you want to create a captcha on client-side, you can use the canvas with distortion filters. Something like [https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/](http://Seems,%20creating%20a%20captcha%20on%20a%20client-side%20isn't%20secure.%20Your%20code%20will%20available%20for%20any%20user.%20Using%20server-side%20is%20a%20better%20decision.%20But%20If%20you%20want%20to%20create%20a%20captcha%20on%20client-side,%20you%20can%20use%20the%20canvas%20with%20distortion%20filters.%20Something%20like%20that:%20https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/)